# Break Parent IF (Conditional)

Tags: php, conditional-statements, break

How can i break parent if in PHP?

example this code:

```
if(true){ // This is parent conditional
    if(true) { // This is child conditional
        break parent conditinal
    }
}

afterBreakDoMe();
```

From code above. I want when child conditional is true. Then it break parent conditional (exit from that conditional) and continue the rest of the code (afterBreakDoMe()).

Update - Real code

```
    $errorMessage = '';
    if(isset($_POST) && count($_POST)) { // Detect some user input
        // validation
        $countryName = trim($_POST['countryName']);         
        if($countryName == ''){ // validation user input, if false. exit from parent if and continue show html input (refer to $Render->output())
            $errorMessage = 'Name must not be empty!'; 
        }

        header('Location: '.$baseUrl.'&page=tableShipping');
    }

    $Render->setTitle('Create New Country');
    $form = $Render->parser('createCountry', array(
        'errorMessage' => $errorMessage,
    ));
    $Render->addContent($form);

    $Render->output();
```

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski `break` does not work for `if`.

Comment: @Gumbo Ah, that's an `if`.  I was too busy copying doc links to read the code.

Comment: `break` is used for loops, not `if` statements. You need to have boolean checks to exit your code

Comment: So really, you just need an `else` case which does the rest of the work in the outer `if`.

Comment: `if (!child_condition_true) {// do the rest of the stuff }` Otherwise it isn't executed and you have effectively broken out.

Comment: The line break parent conditional if only for explanation purpose. Maybe there is some command to stop the if like `endif`?

Comment: can you post the code you actually want to use? It might be that all you need to do is if (something && something_else)

Comment: you just need an else. 33 minutes have passed. i suspect the answer is already below

Comment: Thank you for all of your answer. It is hard for me to decide the right answer since all of it look right :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a variable and an extra if-statement:

```
$errorMessage = '';
$emptyCountry = false;
if(isset($_POST) && count($_POST)) { // Detect some user input
    // validation
    $emptyCountry = trim($_POST['countryName']) == '';
    if($emptyCountry){ // validation user input, if false.
        $errorMessage = 'Name must not be empty!'; 
    }

    header('Location: '.$baseUrl.'&page=tableShipping');
}
if (!emptyCountry) {
    $Render->setTitle('Create New Country');
    $form = $Render->parser('createCountry', array(
        'errorMessage' => $errorMessage,
    ));
    $Render->addContent($form);
}

$Render->output();
```

Comment: oh right, we can use extra variable for that. How stupid iam @_@

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do that (except using `goto`, which is taboo), and should not do that. Swapping functionality for simplicity is a bad idea.

Based on your "real" code, your program flow doesn't make sense.

```
if($countryName == ''){ // validation user input, if false. exit from parent if and continue show html input (refer to $Render->output())
```

So, if it's `true`, you're going to set `$errorMessage`, then exit, leave the page, and never use it again? Why? You might as well just forget the error message, call the `header()`, then call `exit;`.

I've created the following code based on what I *think* you want to happen, and commented it as an explanation:

```
$errorMessage = '';
if(isset($_POST) && count($_POST)) { // Detect some user input
    // validation
    $countryName = trim($_POST['countryName']);         
    if($countryName == ''){ // validation user input, if false. exit from parent if and continue show html input (refer to $Render->output())
        $errorMessage = 'Name must not be empty!'; 
    } else {
        // If there is no error, continue forward.
        header('Location: '.$baseUrl.'&page=tableShipping');
        exit; // Leave the page execution since you've applied a header.
    }
}

// This will only execute if there is an error, since we left the page otherwise.
$Render->setTitle('Create New Country');
$form = $Render->parser('createCountry', array(
    'errorMessage' => $errorMessage,
));
$Render->addContent($form);

$Render->output();
```

All in all, consider the flow of your program in order to determine *what happens next*, not *what to skip*.

Answer (score 1):

Simple

```
if (true) {
   if (true) {
       // Do stuff
       // It will then break automaticly
       // but if the condition here is false you got the else ;)
   } else {

   }
}
```

Comment: Nope, what i want is the exit from parent if.

Comment: @GusDeCooL THe point is that you only put the _other_ stuff in the parent `if` in that else case.  Therefore, if the child condition is _not_ true, it will be executed, and if the child condition is true, it _won't_ be executed. That's the same as breaking the parent `if`.

Comment: Michael Berkowski, what he said is right. Think about it. if the first one is true it checks if the other one is true. if the other one is true it will do the stuff and exit the parent if. It wont go into the else even if you set a variable to the child if and changed it to false after you went into the child if. So that might not have made sense to you but I suggest figuring it out.

Comment: @ArtursLapins These comments were from before the OP added the actual code.

Answer (score 1):

Use [goto](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php). This is used for jumping in code

Comment: Is there any alternative for php 5.2? Go to is available since 5.3

Comment: [No, don't use `goto`. That's just plain taboo.](https://www.google.com/search?q=why+is+goto+bad) There is.. well.. *always* a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

```php
$errorMessage = '';
do {
     if(isset($_POST) && count($_POST)) { // Detect some user input
        // validation
        $countryName = trim($_POST['countryName']);         
        if($countryName == ''){ // validation user input, if false. exit from parent if and continue show html input (refer to $Render->output())
            $errorMessage = 'Name must not be empty!';
            break;
        }

        header('Location: '.$baseUrl.'&page=tableShipping');
    }
while(false);// only for break
```

Comment: `break` does not work in `if`; it only works in `for`/`foreach`.

Comment: Added do while block for break

Answer (score 1):

Now that I can read the real code sample I think what you need to do is simple put all the conditionals together in a single. Using `goto` will get the job done but can easily make you code hard to read and maintain. Perhaps its time to rethink the program flow. 
Anyway, what I am saying is something like this:

```
if(!empty($_POST) && isset($_POST['countryName']) && (trim($_POST['countryName']) == '')){
    $errorMessage = 'Name must not be empty!'; 
}

...
```